# How to get id of the saved record in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am doing this from the console but I'd like to do this in my code too. Basically I am trying to add a record to the table and then get the id back.

```
>> @record = Physician.create(:pname => "someone2")
=> #<Physician id: nil, pname: "someone2", pgroup: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, userid: nil, storeid: nil, licexpdate: nil, address: nil>
>> @record.save
=> false
>>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `@record.save` returns false, the item wasn't saved and it doesn't have an ID. Use `@record.errors.full_messages` to see what went wrong

Answer (score 2):

When you successfully save your object, you can access its ID property and get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating new record make sure that you are providing values for all mandatory columns. If @record.save returns true it means record saved successfully. Get id of it using @record.id

Answer (score -5):

```
@record=Record.create(:name=>'vidur')
last_record_save_id=Record.last.id
```

Comment: This answer deserves 100 +10's! Thanks man, you saved my day :)

Comment: This is actually very wrong approach. This set of operations is not atomic. You can have parallel request and you might get wrong ID. Also last doesn't quarantee order (at least not in Rails 3). Create returns valid record with ID, if the save was successful. Just get @record.id.

Comment: Yes @acidburn2k you are right I agree with you in parallel requests you are not very sure about the id which will be received of that particular record which you are assuming to be.